# Approximation of minimum bandwidth on binary trees

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reference-request, approximation

Minimum bandwidth problem is to a find an ordering of graph nodes on integer line that minimizes the largest distance between any two adjacent nodes.

The decision problem is NP-complete even for binary trees. [Complexity Results for Bandwidth Minimization. Garey, Graham, Johnson and Knuth, SIAM J. Appl. Math., Vol. 34, No.3, 1978](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2100947).

What is the best known efficient approximability result for computing minimum bandwidth on binary trees? What is best known conditional hardness of approximation result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Blache et. al, On Approximation Intractability of the Bandwidth Problem, 1997](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.5794&rep=rep1&type=pdf) confirms there is no **PTAS** for the problem unless $\text{P} = \text{NP}$, even for (binary) trees. [Unger W, The Complexity of the Approximation of the Bandwidth Problem, 1998](http://www.computer.org/comp/proceedings/focs/1998/9172/00/91720082.pdf) show that for any constant $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is no polynomial time approximation algorithm with an approximation factor of $k$. So, unfortunately there's no **PTAS** nor **APX** for the problem.

However, for some types of graphs, the problem can be solved or approximated in polynomial time. For a recent survey, see [Petit J., Addenda to the Survey of Layout Problems, 2011](http://albcom.lsi.upc.edu/ojs/index.php/beatcs/article/view/30/108). In the survey, see Tables 3, 4 and 8. The survey also gives a nice list of references if you want to dig in deeper to some direction. This is an more updated version of the older survey by [Diaz et al., A survey of Graph Layout Problems, 2002](ftp://ftp-sop.inria.fr/mascotte/personnel/Stephane.Perennes/DPS02.pdf).

In case you are interested in the exact algorithm as well, I think currently the fastest one is given by [Cygan M. and Pilipczuk M., Even Faster Exact Bandwidth, 2012](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.1661). The algorithm runs in $O(4.83^n)$ time.